# How to get billing information programmatically from Google Cloud Platform? Is there any API's there.?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I want write utility which fetches billing information for my project but I am not able to find any specific API from GCP to do the same. I tried a couple of APIs like getBillingInfo but these APIs just give information about billing account, not the pricing. They have the mechanism to export billing data to file but I want to do it programmatically. Is there any API to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way that I am aware of is to export the Cloud billing to BigQuery. The process (document) to export Cloud Billing to BigQuery can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery

Once the export is done, the billing information including the price and services is available in almost realtime on BigQuery table. Once it's available on BigQuery there are numerous ways of extracting the information. A good solution would be to have Data Studio on Google Cloud to send you a periodic report on your billing information.